# I am using nested for loop in angular but when I run the code outer loop is not working only inner loop works. check below code

Tags: angular, loops, for-loop

I am using nested for loop in angular but when I run the code outer loop is not working only inner loop works. check below code:

```
          for(var j=resom-1; j <= reso+1; j++ ){


    for (var i=0; i <= res.length; i++ ){

      if (res[i].type=== "session"){

      const amo = res[i].amount;
      const rat = res[i].rate;
      const run = +res[i].run;
      const finalAmo  = (amo*rat)/100;

      if(res[i].kl==="l")
     {
       if(run <=j){
        amounta = amounta+finalAmo;
       }
       else{
         amounta =amounta -amo;
       }
     }
      else
     {
       if(run>j){
         amounta = amounta+amo;
       }
       else{
         amounta = amounta-finalAmo
       }

     }

      }
      console.log(amounta);
    }


    console.log("j is"+j);
    console.log("amount is"+amounta);

    let runDataObj = new RunData();
    runDataObj.run = j;
    runDataObj.amount= amounta;



    this.runDataList.push(runDataObj);
    console.log("data list"+this.runDataList);


}
```

Value of resom=98 and reso=101.
in the console screen also I just get the first console.log's output.

Answer (score 0):

Your nested Loop working properly

```
 let resom =98;
    let reso =101
    for (var j = resom - 1; j <= reso + 1; j++) {
      for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

        console.log("innser loop");
        console.log("i value " + i);

      }
        console.log("outer loop loop");
        console.log("j value " + j);

    }
  }
```

**[stackblitz Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yumzek)**

if Your Share sample **res** array ,it will more help

Comment: res is an array of objects and this object has entities like rate, amount etc. everything is working fine I am even getting output for console.log(amounta);  but program just ends after the inner loop. at start I get value of J but as soon as inner loop complets it ends the method I have even tried to debug but found nothing